# Longest Palindrome Edge Case due to String / StringBuilder Equality

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, palindrome

This code doesn't work for the test case: `aacabdkacaa`, but it works for `babad` or `cbbd`. I wrote a print statement to debug and realized the code thinks that the strings `aacakdbacaa` and `aacabdkacaa` are equivalent for some reason. They clearly aren't, so what am I missing?

```
class Solution {
    public String longestPalindrome(String s) {
        String longPal = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            for(int j = s.length()-1; j >= i; j--) {
                if(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.substring(i, j+1));
                    if(sb.reverse().toString().equals(sb.toString()) 
                       && sb.toString().length() > longPal.length()) {
                        longPal = sb.toString();
                        System.out.println(sb.toString()+" equals "+sb.reverse().toString());
                    }
                    sb.setLength(0);
                }
            }
        }
        return longPal;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code does not think that `aacakdbacaa` and `aacabdkacaa` are equal but only that `sb.reverse().toString().equals(sb.toString()` is `true`. Which it is, and all the time (regardless of what is inside the StringBuilder). Can you spot why that is always true?

Comment: @Ma3x is it because it is comparing the same StringBuilder to itself? But even still, I'm calling the .toString() function _before_ the .equals() comparison, so why wouldn't the StringBuilder be turned into a String before the comparison and return the expected result?

Comment: @Ma3x I got it to work by storing the contents of the StringBuilder within a new String before the comparison - thank you for the help. But I still can't quite grasp why the toString() function didn't convert the SB object to a string before the comparsion?

Comment: it did convert it, but it is a bit long to explain that's why I was trying to write a full answer. I can still write down an answer if you want.

Comment: @Ma3x I'd greatly appreciate any insight - thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code does not think that `aacakdbacaa` and `aacabdkacaa` are equal.

The first part of the condition in the `if` statement is this

```
sb.reverse().toString().equals(sb.toString())
```

So what the code (JVM) thinks is that this condition is `true`.
Why is that? What hidden knowledge is behind this (because there is some)?

The hidden knowledge part (it is not really hidden, it is in the documentation) is that StringBuilder `reverse` method changes the state of the StringBuilder (almost all SB methods do). The `reverse` method also returns the StringBuilder instance itself (some other SB methods do as well).

So the call to `sb.reverse()` just reverses the contents of the StringBuilder instance and returns the instance itself (the same instance that is!). The instance hasn't changed, just its inner state has changed.

Then we call `toString()` on it, which returns the `String` representation of the current state (as expected).

Then we call `equals` on the returned `String` and we pass into `equals` `sb.toString()` as the value for the first parameter. But `sb` is the same instance as what was returned from `sb.reverse()` before. Its state hasn't changed in between, so we get the same `String` representation returned from the call to `sb.toString()`.

That is why

```
sb.reverse().toString().equals(sb.toString())
```

is true.

We could write it a bit differently and still get the same result

```
String s1 = sb.reverse().toString() // sb state changed here when .reverse() was called
String s2 = sb.toString()
s1.equals(s2) // true
```

Or like this, which makes it quite obvious

```
sb.reverse() // sb state changed here
String s1 = sb.toString()
String s2 = sb.toString()
s1.equals(s2) // true
```

However, we get a different result, if we use this order

```
String s1 = sb.toString()
sb.reverse() // sb state changed here
String s2 = sb.toString()
s1.equals(s2) // now it depends, true if palindrome, false otherwise!
```

which is the same as

```
String s1 = sb.toString()
String s2 = sb.reverse().toString()
s1.equals(s2) // true if palindrome, false otherwise!
```

So this would be the correct check to check for a palindrome

```
sb.toString().equals(sb.reverse().toString())
```

Bonus: The practice to return the same instance from a method call is called [Fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Comment: I'd put `sb.reverse()` in a seperate line for the "not working equivalent" example, so `sb.reverse(); String s1 = sb.toString(); String s2 = sb.toString(); s1.equals(s2) // true`. Just for some better "effect" :)

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Nice catch! I added your suggestion, and another one for the "working" equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

StringBuilder's reverse() method causes it's character sequence to be replaced by the reverse of the sequence, so sb.reverse().toString().equals(sb.toString()) always results true.
declare another string `String p = sb.toString()` then use it to compare `sb.reverse().toString().equals(p.toString())` may solve the problem.